# merging shapefile county geodata with R dataframe with missing county data

Tags: r, merge, shapefile, choropleth

I have a shapefile (US) and a list of counties (biz) with data that I'd like to convert to a choropleth map. There is data missing, so not every county FIPS is present in the biz dataframe. I've filtered both the shapefile and the biz R dataframe so that each contain the same countyfips, but I am still getting the following error when I try to merge the two to create a spatial dataframe.

```
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys, data = input@data): row.names of data and Polygons IDs do not match
```

I've tried:

```
library(rgdal)
merge(US, biz, by =  "FIPS", match.ID = FALSE, duplicateGeoms = T)
```

and

```
sp::merge(US, biz, by =  "FIPS")
```

What am I missing here?

Below is how I loaded the shapefile:

```
# download shape (a little less detail than in the other scripts)
f <- tempfile()
download.file("http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip", destfile = f)
unzip(f, exdir = ".")
US <- shapefile("gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp")

# leave out AK, HI, and PR (state FIPS: 02, 15, and 72)
US <- US[!(US$STATE %in% c("02","15","72")),]  

# create key column
US$FIPS <- paste0(US$STATE, US$COUNTY)
```

And the following is the first 100 rows of my biz data:

```
structure(list(FIPS = c(10001, 10003, 10005, 11001, 12001, 12003, 
12005, 12007, 12009, 12011, 12013, 12015, 12017, 12019, 12021, 
12023, 12027, 12031, 12033, 12035, 12037, 12039, 12041, 12045, 
12049, 12051, 12053, 12055, 12057, 12061, 12063, 12065, 12069, 
12071, 12073, 12075, 12081, 12083, 12085, 12086, 12087, 12089, 
12091, 12093, 12095, 12097, 12099, 12101, 12103, 12105, 12107, 
12109, 12111, 12113, 12115, 12117, 12119, 12121, 12123, 12127, 
12129, 12131, 12133, 13001, 13009, 13013, 13015, 13021, 13029, 
13031, 13033, 13035, 13039, 13045, 13047, 13051, 13055, 13057, 
13059, 13063, 13067, 13069, 13071, 13073, 13075, 13077, 13081, 
13083, 13085, 13087, 13089, 13095, 13097, 13103, 13105, 13107, 
13109, 13111, 13113, 13115), merch_perc_change = c(-0.999999997419426, 
-0.999999960099927, -0.999999463606016, -0.999999999992747, -0.999999589415816, 
-0.999776694518714, -0.999998139171249, -0.923691427414423, -0.999962755064437, 
-0.999999297609172, 6.86356300955509, -0.999796407354303, -0.999999920342331, 
-0.999989017442108, -0.999999987828828, -0.999687144654275, -0.999809854633837, 
-0.999994022173781, -0.999997564726118, -0.999991074764553, -0.999978132819644, 
-0.999048191581644, -0.999816255794303, -0.99999999999953, -0.999998368294174, 
-0.999983530324202, -0.999999959737609, -0.999999999915238, -0.9999998961883, 
-0.999997217365727, -0.999999486649557, -0.998247739967963, -0.999998585480854, 
-0.99999734246251, -0.99998316042666, -0.999997698874625, -0.999999749503321, 
-0.999999812749288, -0.999935448837586, -0.999999220586342, -0.99999956646977, 
-0.999999999979337, -0.999999311106202, -0.99798206258435, -0.999999372093591, 
-0.999999923772396, -0.999995867853803, -0.999997734665119, -0.999999905345573, 
-0.999998463559358, -0.99999999205029, -0.999999991820707, -0.99990638439578, 
-0.999999312175056, -0.999999978238681, -0.999999607559491, -0.999997940723336, 
-0.999965827464078, -0.99987412039642, -0.999998284179988, -0.999788909786871, 
-0.999999999391236, -0.999558269566805, -0.999999999991671, -0.999999896605606, 
-0.999999811038711, -0.99957117015121, -0.999997531666568, -0.999891490436958, 
-0.99996557149293, -0.999997779404573, -0.999999995034784, -0.999999862415467, 
-0.999984320487476, -0.999998471029504, -0.999999475141075, -0.999989299298126, 
-0.99999700303135, -0.999999983041563, -0.999976248756212, -0.999997959804029, 
-0.999906120208879, -0.974494760294364, -0.999996351284903, -0.999999987539243, 
-0.999314090769117, -0.999999999937565, -0.999999999996, -0.999227737065879, 
-0.999999894274373, -0.999999275234666, -0.99999972998535, -0.999989925844005, 
-0.999980780315507, 11.9726427425268, -0.999999845161106, -0.999985089588605, 
-0.99999999506689, -0.999997272506931, -0.999999600943781), rev_perc_change = c(-0.999999868770726, 
-0.999999990632098, -0.999978350417758, -1, -0.999999977063738, 
-0.999999557925536, 2.96734401473508, -0.999999978115999, -0.999999876658537, 
-0.999998644384056, -0.999999948925146, -0.999957383116217, -0.999999999202153, 
-0.799103739676736, -0.999999999730313, 52.5419769811163, -0.989897752573793, 
-0.999990771638404, -0.999999097277337, -0.999999056612073, -0.999999999997651, 
-0.791258306382895, -0.835408375403338, -0.999999949255092, -0.999999995917852, 
-0.995526573454658, -0.999980744495764, -0.999999999999523, -0.999999967084492, 
-0.999999795346701, -0.865997270001737, -0.998547105111494, -0.999999994311607, 
-0.999999986040664, -0.999991969242583, -0.999644160435803, -0.999999761949245, 
-0.999999615053214, -0.439117774567191, -0.999999973586027, -0.999999999999614, 
-0.999997934384089, -0.999999490767057, -0.904747175661281, -0.999999996424736, 
-0.999999995884735, -0.999999970209871, -0.999993644951214, -0.999999928595513, 
-0.999997760171338, -0.999999999201456, -0.999999998546284, -0.999996541137073, 
-0.999999998767801, -0.999999999803137, -0.999999882081287, -0.999998232474645, 
-0.999999998321198, -0.999999999134723, -0.999999877739019, -0.999938452181625, 
-0.999999999696075, -0.999971062558217, -1, -0.999999999998913, 
-0.999999936705897, -0.999999972777953, -0.999993970088101, -0.767994542540064, 
-0.999997956578155, -0.999999999999991, -0.999999999504284, -0.999999988489851, 
-0.999998275694059, -0.999978229417813, -0.999999893084442, -0.99999998787768, 
-0.999974986845167, -0.999999999116068, -0.999998633242769, -0.999998804829792, 
-0.982278889848666, -0.364341840741643, -0.999999997786457, -0.999999976614482, 
-0.998382508964322, -0.999999999999671, -0.999999196325065, -0.999975011497777, 
-0.998599571268165, -0.999999979094997, -0.997753198487314, -0.999999926318692, 
-0.154416470074132, -0.928951601468295, -0.994011394007064, -0.999999999462366, 
-0.999999999998392, -0.999999919376053, -0.99999990340994), religion = c(0.041286647, 
0.02607471, 0.066732876, 0.044134054, 0.05952625, 0.06738507, 
0.059015673, 0.111649066, 0.025701044, 0.01340009, 0.15596099, 
0.020686807, 0.041033328, 0.028240733, 0.017688353, 0.10048646, 
0.09002863, 0.045010816, 0.0599233, 0.023459796, 0.18008809, 
0.15380068, 0.10875068, 0.16463679, 0.12366201, 0.08062692, 0.020737456, 
0.072489396, 0.02980364, 0.03522147, 0.18431833, 0.2241213, 0.04967877, 
0.020767821, 0.042845365, 0.114026226, 0.025252016, 0.050515506, 
0.028480459, 0.011976497, 0.051216464, 0.071065746, 0.060021035, 
0.0671975, 0.022543803, 0.026054224, 0.012819406, 0.012850202, 
0.019244831, 0.052286506, 0.104308784, 0.021517357, 0.026059527, 
0.04549559, 0.026263602, 0.018891444, 0.04764373, 0.14865479, 
0.17848434, 0.032876275, 0.074900545, 0.13018908, 0.14712808, 
0.22409584, 0.06142032, 0.04922596, 0.058575258, 0.080876544, 
0.054859933, 0.05560649, 0.14968075, 0.09415126, 0.076041564, 
0.07222162, 0.04100541, 0.059602886, 0.19613168, 0.022500644, 
0.035217304, 0.023242751, 0.01764376, 0.12785666, 0.1234028, 
0.03073952, 0.13650659, 0.060998723, 0.12673242, 0.11131127, 
0.10484315, 0.20243417, 0.024939083, 0.07396702, 0.03522846, 
0.07814219, 0.21069641, 0.14236231, 0.14371029, 0.15000819, 0.050455987, 
0.099605545), civic = c(0.09236666, 0.10866666, 0.08693332, 0.10866666, 
0.10323332, 0.048899993, 0.09779999, 0.048899993, 0.10866666, 
0.10866666, 0.02173333, 0.081499994, 0.081499994, 0.09779999, 
0.09779999, 0.05433333, 0.05976666, 0.10866666, 0.10866666, 0.081499994, 
0.06519999, 0.06519999, 0.02173333, 0.06519999, 0.05976666, 0.08693332, 
0.10323332, 0.08693332, 0.10866666, 0.09779999, 0.06519999, 0.03803333, 
0.09236666, 0.10866666, 0.10866666, 0.05976666, 0.09779999, 0.09779999, 
0.09779999, 0.10866666, 0.09779999, 0.09236666, 0.09236666, 0.07063332, 
0.10866666, 0.09236666, 0.10866666, 0.09779999, 0.10866666, 0.10866666, 
0.07606666, 0.09779999, 0.07606666, 0.08693332, 0.10866666, 0.10866666, 
0.08693332, 0.05976666, 0.048899993, 0.09779999, 0.06519999, 
0.07063332, 0.05976666, 0.05433333, 0.07606666, 0.06519999, 0.07063332, 
0.10866666, 0.06519999, 0.081499994, 0.032599997, 0.02173333, 
0.081499994, 0.05976666, 0.048899993, 0.10866666, 0.03803333, 
0.08693332, 0.10866666, 0.09236666, 0.10866666, 0.07063332, 0.07063332, 
0.07606666, 0.03803333, 0.07606666, 0.05433333, 0.05433333, 0.05433333, 
0.05433333, 0.09779999, 0.081499994, 0.08693332, 0.06519999, 
0.03803333, 0.05976666, 0.02173333, 0.048899993, 0.10323332, 
0.081499994), ethnic = c(0.3970396, 0.37897056, 0.5357585, 0.24768388, 
0.40286815, 0.6357579, 0.6016036, 0.5114627, 0.6255658, 0.3186922, 
0.5825614, 0.7621388, 0.8317045, 0.6124228, 0.6632664, 0.52478975, 
0.49357843, 0.30896062, 0.39672756, 0.6146619, 0.662264, 0.283978, 
0.79085565, 0.5306848, 0.6103033, 0.35079825, 0.7638138, 0.64863324, 
0.44819558, 0.6953889, 0.40650934, 0.3398254, 0.61111623, 0.6295637, 
0.3380776, 0.67512846, 0.61698794, 0.5896463, 0.721169, 0.4455908, 
0.7558898, 0.75864416, 0.5891671, 0.65199465, 0.29523754, 0.43643963, 
0.46105385, 0.7583519, 0.62372357, 0.50434506, 0.53839517, 0.74449384, 
0.45155495, 0.7162366, 0.7817946, 0.5408662, 0.68203306, 0.6332905, 
0.49937886, 0.6118857, 0.626454, 0.6951653, 0.5778341, 0.41941065, 
0.32683736, 0.5616461, 0.5903009, 0.28805655, 0.5589603, 0.38802063, 
0.33231544, 0.43056065, 0.47309256, 0.5226548, 0.8516469, 0.29380715, 
0.66506696, 0.6927326, 0.33732903, 0.3049189, 0.29078054, 0.35410964, 
0.32911754, 0.5134419, 0.37947673, 0.51836216, 0.3146671, 0.8988029, 
0.89620274, 0.29536778, 0.24357241, 0.38732207, 0.308964, 0.61849403, 
0.39014798, 0.3550223, 0.30616927, 0.91790694, 0.43637908, 0.5408756
), language = c(0.9028321, 0.8534756, 0.9003864, 0.8477236, 0.85861427, 
0.9763271, 0.91966915, 0.96824694, 0.89786947, 0.6191133, 0.9333193, 
0.9033248, 0.9319655, 0.9029625, 0.6809509, 0.93964654, 0.70345926, 
0.86834, 0.91468996, 0.8441426, 0.92808974, 0.9063144, 0.9645202, 
0.9443971, 0.5804937, 0.56604165, 0.8854753, 0.81346387, 0.7352802, 
0.8515354, 0.94880205, 0.93205106, 0.877309, 0.7811706, 0.9077789, 
0.9318178, 0.8326978, 0.8790868, 0.8538892, 0.25064504, 0.7663783, 
0.9555273, 0.907167, 0.7620087, 0.66066307, 0.5361982, 0.72005004, 
0.8630133, 0.8662945, 0.81044525, 0.9097693, 0.9163808, 0.7922232, 
0.92694986, 0.8709022, 0.81088173, 0.90886694, 0.92950064, 0.9560861, 
0.8681097, 0.96221495, 0.92667896, 0.9416113, 0.8984488, 0.9538415, 
0.8885773, 0.9254957, 0.94662046, 0.9305949, 0.9372623, 0.98557174, 
0.96830726, 0.94496214, 0.923303, 0.9672361, 0.9219519, 0.96036005, 
0.87589335, 0.8607454, 0.7873163, 0.7968753, 0.89746803, 0.83082134, 
0.8995851, 0.9295714, 0.9215403, 0.96248287, 0.9729186, 0.955991, 
0.9710674, 0.8113927, 0.9619904, 0.8924399, 0.96472365, 0.9513764, 
0.94352907, 0.86856884, 0.9584267, 0.88784045, 0.9044569), voteage = c(0.5415052, 
0.5250972, 0.5858911, 0.57861066, 0.60942423, 0.558716, 0.5892219, 
0.6370349, 0.6141516, 0.3952495, 0.5966508, 0.69935966, 0.70640314, 
0.52056634, 0.43017876, 0.59642285, 0.37977982, 0.53641015, 0.5947154, 
0.59636533, 0.68313015, 0.524484, 0.60493284, 0.6814822, 0.26147988, 
0.24641654, 0.62900823, 0.60015863, 0.4710629, 0.59511346, 0.6425276, 
0.66375273, 0.5933129, 0.52887684, 0.6171358, 0.60419106, 0.53888094, 
0.620374, 0.614735, 0.24189119, 0.6001134, 0.6118948, 0.57089466, 
0.43977982, 0.44113994, 0.39214894, 0.4736451, 0.58449423, 0.6172989, 
0.5052691, 0.56155217, 0.5756319, 0.5006779, 0.56436056, 0.64906085, 
0.53386456, 0.79360616, 0.5629912, 0.64399046, 0.6279944, 0.61143416, 
0.6120734, 0.6178282, 0.51169556, 0.63740486, 0.46528107, 0.49653965, 
0.5406704, 0.49688926, 0.6171718, 0.51588005, 0.60201925, 0.540264, 
0.52046335, 0.5638834, 0.55689573, 0.5832646, 0.45817313, 0.58187026, 
0.37612963, 0.4259325, 0.49137145, 0.39633512, 0.49645153, 0.49827608, 
0.48816267, 0.5490801, 0.61691815, 0.58953744, 0.5359645, 0.43509322, 
0.54484385, 0.44624743, 0.5085251, 0.5765146, 0.53727007, 0.45505175, 
0.6727599, 0.493701, 0.52082986), local = c(0.11346269, 0.0821763, 
0.09865325, 0.13039602, 0.16706811, 0.1925357, 0.18262136, 0.20276488, 
0.16904168, 0.18558133, 0.23628975, 0.19656563, 0.22064485, 0.19406708, 
0.13554244, 0.18911618, 0.1964137, 0.1288788, 0.1642498, 0.2320314, 
0.2406299, 0.23134439, 0.2193604, 0.21352763, 0.18684117, 0.2663458, 
0.18552017, 0.1936251, 0.15774018, 0.16654506, 0.2464689, 0.2213913, 
0.19595641, 0.17701498, 0.16920264, 0.18539564, 0.19038261, 0.18990363, 
0.17630382, 0.16714683, 0.16716042, 0.18136276, 0.14041798, 0.21676183, 
0.13718824, 0.1693134, 0.16400187, 0.19431508, 0.15682065, 0.20015918, 
0.22922051, 0.15314136, 0.20060387, 0.17444389, 0.17039652, 0.1454538, 
0.234232, 0.16478789, 0.1899709, 0.18571664, 0.26345906, 0.2111755, 
0.27364796, 0.16966473, 0.16955985, 0.21253699, 0.22058052, 0.15532793, 
0.15032071, 0.15741009, 0.2304608, 0.250423, 0.20964451, 0.17636389, 
0.16328937, 0.16403592, 0.16296567, 0.1623544, 0.17546876, 0.17806159, 
0.13644126, 0.23888248, 0.1776321, 0.15040636, 0.16471201, 0.17668277, 
0.24506003, 0.14990062, 0.19695675, 0.20724353, 0.15140234, 0.19517402, 
0.18235727, 0.19484001, 0.18699574, 0.16355312, 0.121629976, 
0.21160316, 0.1918851, 0.16756512), education = c(0.6537678, 
0.6364562, 0.5315682, 0.6130346, 0.72199595, 0.45010185, 0.68533605, 
0.51221997, 0.6629328, 0.6099796, 0.4124236, 0.65784115, 0.56619143, 
0.67209774, 0.52138495, 0.57331973, 0.1934827, 0.66496944, 0.700611, 
0.67413443, 0.45112014, 0.43380857, 0.50610995, 0.37576377, 0.24847251, 
0.3940937, 0.6252546, 0.47352344, 0.6262729, 0.5875764, 0.55906314, 
0.5366599, 0.59063137, 0.59572303, 0.7443992, 0.55397147, 0.55906314, 
0.59979635, 0.58350307, 0.56109977, 0.5682281, 0.62729126, 0.7209776, 
0.44093686, 0.6405295, 0.62118125, 0.5712831, 0.6099796, 0.65478617, 
0.5549898, 0.50814664, 0.65478617, 0.57026476, 0.65580446, 0.62729126, 
0.68329936, 0.4857434, 0.4562118, 0.42260695, 0.6863544, 0.51221997, 
0.54887986, 0.4154786, 0.49694502, 0.5875764, 0.5641548, 0.49083507, 
0.5397149, 0.6201629, 0.7739307, 0.49694502, 0.33604884, 0.70162934, 
0.59063137, 0.63441956, 0.62729126, 0.48472506, 0.6120163, 0.71588594, 
0.598778, 0.6171079, 0.49083507, 0.48472506, 0.5916497, 0.58655804, 
0.59775966, 0.54276985, 0.6822811, 0.65173113, 0.4582485, 0.6120163, 
0.62729126, 0.5967413, 0.55600816, 0.36863542, 0.45723015, 0.401222, 
0.6466395, 0.65784115, 0.5875764), employ = c(0.5028835, 0.57900804, 
0.47750866, 0.5213379, 0.5121107, 0.4463668, 0.5074971, 0.32987314, 
0.449827, 0.5397924, 0.28950405, 0.2802768, 0.23644753, 0.5374856, 
0.44059977, 0.33679354, 0.35178775, 0.5363322, 0.4152249, 0.37600923, 
0.37139562, 0.32064593, 0.34256056, 0.3252595, 0.37831604, 0.37600923, 
0.30449826, 0.28835064, 0.5432526, 0.3690888, 0.30680507, 0.34256056, 
0.42214534, 0.4152249, 0.5432526, 0.3656286, 0.43367937, 0.3287197, 
0.39792386, 0.49942333, 0.57324106, 0.49019605, 0.5098039, 0.38523644, 
0.56747407, 0.5224914, 0.46597463, 0.4106113, 0.48212227, 0.44059977, 
0.32641295, 0.5374856, 0.38985008, 0.46251443, 0.37946942, 0.5859285, 
0.118800454, 0.4083045, 0.34371397, 0.44059977, 0.49250287, 0.4544406, 
0.36678204, 0.5340254, 0.38177624, 0.5201846, 0.5363322, 0.42791235, 
0.5940023, 0.46251443, 0.39677048, 0.43137255, 0.44059977, 0.47866204, 
0.5524798, 0.5098039, 0.37024224, 0.61937714, 0.4913495, 0.4948097, 
0.6297578, 0.4394464, 0.4936563, 0.55709344, 0.4544406, 0.5870819, 
0.38292962, 0.48096886, 0.54094577, 0.461361, 0.5282584, 0.37024224, 
0.5340254, 0.5524798, 0.4175317, 0.38869664, 0.48096886, 0.40138412, 
0.5928489, 0.46943483), socialcap = c(1.2465897, 1.1796607, 0.99583554, 
1.213838, 1.2140356, 1.0433682, 1.1867946, 1.0998459, 1.1968888, 
0.9863519, 1.0743337, 1.2542336, 1.2588876, 1.167894, 1.0432669, 
1.0626454, 0.88172776, 1.0901438, 1.1371455, 1.1487094, 1.0707088, 
1.1323296, 1.0424548, 1.3017348, 0.7089147, 0.99225324, 1.006372, 
1.0797297, 1.0777289, 1.0685663, 1.1497757, 1.0380225, 1.1510758, 
1.0681523, 1.1533836, 1.1480858, 1.109215, 1.0647533, 1.108393, 
0.86751366, 1.1352568, 1.250612, 1.1412742, 0.9820876, 1.0141772, 
0.9327179, 0.9930749, 1.0881922, 1.2074403, 1.0714755, 1.1362286, 
1.1118767, 0.96056145, 1.2471367, 1.2069551, 0.9745213, 1.0848411, 
1.1748116, 1.166508, 1.1300496, 1.1630167, 1.1959319, 1.1653817, 
1.0205215, 1.0896816, 1.0423381, 1.0528433, 1.1218456, 1.1675899, 
1.1556351, 1.0114185, 1.0285435, 1.2299659, 1.0582013, 1.1651775, 
1.124054, 1.0567757, 1.1237862, 1.135855, 0.9389708, 1.0796958, 
0.9262693, 0.8858328, 1.1860313, 0.9620687, 1.1273029, 1.0348538, 
1.1883315, 1.1845229, 1.0326669, 1.0741078, 1.1087412, 1.0355263, 
1.1264266, 1.0276779, 0.95914507, 0.9550716, 1.1294575, 1.1779915, 
1.1125866)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

This is how I filtered the two dataframes to have the same county fips:

```
US <- US[which(US$FIPS %in% c(test$FIPS)),]
biz <- biz[which(biz$FIPS %in% c(US$FIPS)),]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!